# PHP PDO: Undefine variable

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have created a database class which is throwing an error of

> Undefined variable: options in C:path/ on line 21

and I cant seem to figure out why.

```
class Db
{
  private static $instance = null;

  private $options = array(
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
  );

  private function __construct() {}

  private function __clone() {}

  public static function getInstance()
  {
    if (!isset(self::$instance)) {
      self::$instance = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb', 'root', '', $options);
    }
    return self::$instance;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `$options` doesn't exist. You should reference the defined one as `$this->options`, but that's not a solution for you as you are using it in a static function: the `$this` context is not available.

You could just define your options in that static method I guess, like below. Not the prettiest solution as now your settings are hidden in your creation-method, but as an example:

```
class Db
{
  private static $instance = null;

  private function __construct() {}

  private function __clone() {}

  public static function getInstance()
  {
    $options = array(
      PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
      PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    );

    if (!isset(self::$instance)) {
      self::$instance = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb', 'root', '', $options);
    }
    return self::$instance;
  }
}
```

The error by the way is quite clear: you are using a variable `$options` that doesn't exist at that point so you get an error that says it's not defined.

Comment: it was quite obvious.